# Does a 32 bit application consume multiple cores/processors

Tags: visual-c++, 32-bit, processor, cpu-cores

A 32 bit application developed in C++ running on multiple machines having 4 or more Cores. And I am analysing cores/processor consumption by the application.  I want to ask, can a 32 bit application use more than one Core? If yes, is there any way to check that?

Comment: It is impossible for a 32-bit app to use less or more cores than a 64-bit app.  Use a debugger if you don't know, the debugger's Threads window is relevant.  Technically you can only truly see how many cores are used effectively with a [concurrency analyzer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx) since there is no guarantee that more than one thread can use more than one core at the same time.  Threads have a habit of locking each other out to keep the code thread-safe.  Task Manager tends to be simple.

Comment: Thanks Hans. Will try using concurrency analyzer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HansPassant can you please confirm one more thing. We don't have any such limitation on 64-bit process, right? That can use all the available CPUs at the same time.

Answer (score 4):

32/64-bit is the number of bits the application uses to address its virtual memory. How many cores the application uses is completely independent from that number.

Typically any application will use as many available cores as it has active threads (as Hans Passant points out correctly, some threads might be blocked waiting for other threads, IO, or similar, in which case they won't be scheduled for any of the cores).

A simple check would be to view the CPU usage for the process in the Task Manager: if the process utilizes less than `100% / number_of_cores` of the CPU then it is effectively single-threaded. If it utilizes more, it means that it runs on more than one core. Your aim should be to make it utilize `100%` of the available CPU by proper use of multi-threading techniques (again, this is unrelated to the 32/64-bit issue).